# Makefile : How to specify where to generate an object

Tags: object, makefile, repository, directory

I would like to specify a repository for an object I generate in my makefile.

I searched for a while but only found elaborate solutions, for a list of objects, while I would like to TARGET ONE OBJECT ONLY.

(makefile is new for me, so the simpler the better)

Here is my code:

```
///////////////////////////////////
*definition of several directories*
*definition of CC, CFLAGS, CInclude*

cutgen: 
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -D__LINUX__ $(CDir)cutgen.c -o cutgen

check: cutgen cutcheck.c *list of objects here*
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -I $(CHeaderDir) cutcheck.c *list of objects here* -o cutcheck
    ./cutcheck

cutcheck.c: cutgen test.o 
    ./cutgen $(CDir)test.c -o cutcheck.c

test.o:  util.o 
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -c $(CInclude) $(CDir)test.c

util.o:  config.o 
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -c $(CInclude) $(GenDir)util.c

...

...

stubs.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFlags) $(CInclude) -c $(StubsDir)stubs.c 

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ cutcheck* cutgen

all: check
///////////////////////////////////
```

Here for example, I would like to generate util.o in the Objects folder. 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(Objects)/util.o:  config.o 
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -c $(CInclude) $(GenDir)util.c -o $@
```

(And are you sure about that prerequisite? I think `$(GenDir)util.c` might be better than `config.o`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! 
Indeed you are right regarding the prerequisite.

However, when I apply your changes :

- If I previously specify a path for "Objects" I get a "*** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop."

- If I replace every occurences of util.o by $(Objects)/util.o then util.o is not generated.

Comment: @JohnBob: I can't reproduce your error. Could you post a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the shortest makefile that ought to produce the object file but fails?

Comment: Hello, I apologize for my late reply.
I began to create a minimal complete example but then was given an alternative solution which fits my needs, so my problem is solved. Here the solution : 
mv util.o ./Objects/
The bash commands move my file to the specified directory.

Thank you very much for your help @Beta !